# How to see asynchronity without callback in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that has integration with my database, but before that I have a function which does some checks:

```
function checkVars (a, b){
   if (a.a1 !== b.b1){
          b.b1 = a.a1;
   }
   // and other 4 vars
 }
```

After this I have a function to insert data into my database.

How can I be sure that my code is going to execute the comparative function before the database function?

I am using a callback, but is that possible without callbacks?

Comment: Simply call your `checkVars()` first. It doesn't do anything asynchronous, so there should be no problem.

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Also, which callback you want to remove? I don't see one in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i be sure that my code is going to execute the comparative function before ?

Assuming you have:

```
checkVars(something, somethingElse);
doDatabaseWork();
```

...you **know** `checkVars` will be called and will run to completion before `doDatabaseWork` is called. Since `checkVars` does all of its work synchronously (it doesn't start any asynchronous processes), the fact it runs to completion before `doDatabaseWork` is called means all of its work is done before `doDatabaseWork`. It's only if `checkVars` starts an asynchronous process that you need to allow for that process not being complete yet when `checkVars` returns (and handle it via callbacks, direct ones or via promises). But what you've described doesn't start an asynchronous process in `checkVars`, so there's nothing to allow for.